# Поиск и вывод значений с заданным условием

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Имеется датафрейм вот такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо при вводе РЦ найти количество вхождений этого РЦ в соответствующий столбец

Написал вот такую функцию, вроде, худо-бедно работает:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("OOS23testcsv.csv")

def findRC(file, stolbec, znachenie):
    i = 0
    for row in file[stolbec]:
        row = str(row)
        if row.count(znachenie):
            i += 1

    return i, znachenie
```

Как теперь реализовать и вшить в эту функцию вывод названия номенклатуры каждой из найденных строк? В коде новичок, если что

В итоге должен вывестись вот такой результат (все строки удовлетворяющие условию поиска, количество таких строк и заданный РЦ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите пример - что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: @CrazyElf , в итоге должно получится вот так:
n строк из столбца (Номенклатура), которые увеличили наш счетчик, а также количество вхождений и заданный РЦ

Comment: И всё-равно не очень понятно. Если это должна быть табличка - покажите, как она должна выглядеть

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил в вопрос

Comment: Хорошо. Я вам пока не подскажу, но эта информация может помочь кому-то другому ответить вам.

Comment: предоставьте воспроизводимый пример данных.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)